# Why does Hyper-V and Windows Backup crash (BSOD) after successfull backup?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, hyper-v, iscsi

Hello I am running Server 2008 R2 with a handful of Hyper-V guest nodes. If Windows backup runs without any of the Hyper-V nodes running, the server is fine. If Hyper-V runs a backup while the Hyper-V nodes are running, it is fine until a few minutes after the backup completes, and then it BSODs. The storage location for the backup is iSCSI - I am wondering if anyone has any input on what might be causing this? I don't have the Hyper-V nodes setup on a vlan and there is only one NIC on the server. Is it possible this is a networking / driver issue, and if so how would I reconfigure the networking to fix this?

Comment: Can you provide some specifics on the BSOD?

Comment: Also, did you do this? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/958662

Comment: @ErnieTheGeek thanks for the link I didn't try that yet - Here are the crash details, I'm unable to open the dump files (Win7SDK won't install for me, working on it) Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name: BlueScreen
  OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.272.7
  Locale ID: 1033

Additional information about the problem:
  BCCode: 1000007e
  BCP1: FFFFFFFFC0000005
  BCP2: FFFFF8000168A480
  BCP3: FFFFF88002769F08
  BCP4: FFFFF88002769760
  OS Version: 6_1_7601
  Service Pack: 1_0
  Product: 272_3

Comment: Follow the technote and try it again, let us know afterwards.

Comment: Cool thanks, I have to wait until the weekend to test this but I'll update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your version of volsnap.sys?  This is probably fixed in the most recent hotfix.

**"0x0000007E" or "0x00000050" Stop error when you create snapshots of a volume in Windows Server 2008 R2 or in Windows 7**
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2460912

**"0x0000007E" Stop error when you run a VSS-based backup application in Windows 7 or in Windows Server 2008 R2**
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2548124

But don't use those hotfixes.  Use the most recent version 6.1.7601.21854 of volsnap.sys availble here:

**Stop error when you create a VSS snapshot backup in Windows 7 SP1 or in Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1: "fvevol!FveFilterDeviceControl+1d0"**
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2708549

or here:

**Computer randomly stops responding after you use the VSS software provider in Windows Server 2008 R2 or in Windows 7**
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2627052

Comment: Thanks this looks promising, my version of volsnap.sys is not the current one - I have to wait until the weekend to test this though but I'll update.

Comment: This worked great, glad it was so simple.

Comment: Glad to hear it helped.